# How can I check if a CocoaPod's module is embedded in a static library?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, static-libraries

I export a library, and it should include all it's dependencies. I have received a complaint from a user that the latest version of the library gives the error "framework not found Alamofire for architecture armv7".

I think I exported the library in the same way as before, and the last update didn't include changes in CocoaPods, which is how I include Alamofire.

How can I check if my `.a` library file includes Alamofire? Can I read modules somehow?

Comment: try using nm command to examine the library.

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda What am I looking for? I tried `nm lib.a | grep Alamofire`, but I did not get any results.